# Python: Getting all information from video

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to wet my toes in using Python for video data.

So, I am trying to open a website like: youtube.com. On the first page that loads up there are a lot of videos.

I want to read name of all videos on the front page and get the information like time length of videos, number of views and what is the link to open them.

I tried a few threads but they are for youtube only. I want to write a code so that it doesn't use the google API.

I don't even have a clue where to start. I tried using urllib but it doesn't work.

Edit:
I don't want to use google API as for example I want to read the videos from NatGeo or HBO.com and gather information about trailers etc.So, I am trying to create a more generic code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the YouTube API? That's your best choice.

Comment: If you don't use the official APIs, your code will be likely to break when the format of the YouTube home page changes in the future. But if you're doing this as a learning exercise, post some of your code and the specific problem you're having. If you really have no idea where to start, take a look at diveintopython.net.

Comment: I am good with Python as a coding language doing mostly scientific and numerical analysis however. So, I have never been exposed to video side of the programming.

Comment: @user1243255 What you're doing isn't exactly working with video data - you'd be getting metadata from the various services (about video name, length, views, etc.), and most likely you will not be able to write something generic/service-agnostic (no one's formatting their data or anything the same, for the most part). A lot of what you have already described is more related to web scraping (and for that, you could use something like `scrapy`).